# Passing R markdown parameters to sql query

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to knit an R markdown file where a user would select a parameter and then have it passed to a query.
It would be something like this:

```
---
title: "markman"
output:
  html_document:
   css: faded.css
params:
  data: 'Johnny'
 ---



## Data

``{r echo = FALSE}


library(RPostgreSQL)
con<-dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), dbname="db", 
host="localhost", port=5432, user="user",password="pass")

query <- paste("select * from table where name= params$data")

data <-dbGetQuery(con,query)

summary(data)
```

I am however getting and error. Whenever I try to knit with parameters, I get that my file has no defined parameters.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to change your query string:

```
query <- paste0("select * from table where name ='", params$data, "'")
```

Also, you have the yaml tabbing incorrect. Try removing the spaces here:

```
---
title: "markman"
output:
  html_document:
   css: faded.css
params:
  data: 'Johnny'
 ---
```

Look at the last line i.e. `---`. There are some spaces in front that need removing.

Comment: Can you paste in the exact error code. Also, can you add in which method you are using to knit.

Comment: I am using Rstudio. Using the 'knit with parameters' option.    The error am getting is a pop up that just says:[No parameters defined] 'There are no parameters for the current markdown document'

Comment: yea, it was yaml tabbing that was causing the error